# These words are so dirty

Tags: java, strings, programming-challenge, regex

**Challenge**:

> Write a program that will clean up the words from extra numbers and symbols.

**Specifications**:

> The first argument is a path to a file.
>   Each line includes a test case with a list of words: letters are both lowercase and uppercase, and are mixed with extra symbols.
>   Print the words separated by spaces in lowercase letters.
>   The length of a test case together with extra symbols can be in a range from 10 to 100 symbols.
>   The number of test cases is 40.

**Solution**:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CleanWords {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(args[0]))) {
            while(input.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(sanitize(input.nextLine()));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            System.out.println(args[0] + " doesn't exist");
        }
    }

    private static String sanitize(String input) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : input.split("[^a-zA-Z]+")) {
            result.append(' ').append(s);
        }
        return result.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
    }
}
```

**Sample Input**:

> ```
> (--9Hello----World...--)  
> Can 0$9 ---you~  
> 13What213are;11you-123+138doing7
> ```

**Sample Output**:

> ```
> hello world  
> can you  
> what are you doing
> ```

I'm wondering if:

1. It would be more efficient to call `trim` within the loop?
2. If there's a less costly way than looping twice between calling both `toLowerCase` and `trim`

These may seem like givens, but it's been a long time since I did one of these, and I wanted to get back into it with a seemingly simple one. I passed on the first try which I largely have CR to thank for. For those interested, the source is [CodeEval.com](https://www.codeeval.com/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be significantly cleaned up and simplified using Java 8. Let's start with a quick review, though before rewriting it all :)

> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>     try (Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(args[0]))) {
> ```

You perform no validation whatsoever here. When this is called without an argument, you'll get a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`... not nice. Validate your inputs (even when the assignment says you'll get a path)

Also you should consider using JSR-203 (aka. `java.nio`) API. It's cleaner and more informative wrt. Exceptions and general handling of problematic inputs.
Also it integrates very nicely with Streams :D

But you're using try-with-resources, which is a good start.

> ```
>         while(input.hasNextLine()) {
>             System.out.println(sanitize(input.nextLine()));
>         }
> ```

This is a small indication your main-method is doing too much. You do:

- Open file
- read that file
- call sanitize
- print
- error handling

Following the Single Responsibility Principle by the letter would mean every single one of these should be a separate method. I personally find that overkill, but I'd at least shift the responsibilities a little by separating result retrieval (aka. `sanitize()`) from printing.

Which gets me to sanitization or rather how you do it:

> ```
>     for (String s : input.split("[^a-zA-Z]+")) {
> ```

What you're doing here is interesting and basically a cool trick, but.. you're cheating around what you actually want.

You want to extract words consisting of [a-z] (case insensitive). What you do is split you String on everything else and then reassemble it.

So there's a few things you could've done instead. First possibility would've been to extract the words with a Pattern and then assembling them, which might've been more obvious:

```
Pattern words = Pattern.compile("([a-z]+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = words.matcher(s);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (m.find()) {
   sb.append(m.group()).append(' ');
}
```

This basically accomplishes the same as your code, but is more explicit as to what you want to match. But this is a lot of code for something dead simple. It boils down to what your split does in combination with the loop.

What you do is replace everything, that's **not** a latin letter with a space. Why not write that?

```
s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", " ");
```

this eliminates the for-loop you have and .. basically does the same :D

Now that we got this out of the way, let's look at how it looks with JSR203 and Streams :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(args[0]))) {
        final String output = lines.map(CleanWords::sanitize)
             .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
        System.out.println(output);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not read File");
    }
}

private static String sanitize(String input) {
     return input.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]+", " ").toLowerCase().trim();
}
```

Comment: +1, though I disagree about the input validation. It's simply unnecessary here, so don't sweat it. I wouldn't even handle the exception at all, and declare `main` to throw instead.

Comment: I was tentative about posting this since I couldn't see much room for improvement. But your answer exemplifies why I love this site. There's always something that can be bettered and truly skilled senpais to show you the way, thank you for the spectacular answer.

Comment: I just realized this, but if you're `joining()` by the line separator and then sending the result to `System.out.println()`, you probably should use `forEach(System.out::println)`.

Comment: @h.j.k then again that would be intermingling responsibilities

Comment: @Vogel612 how so? In this specific example, it can be part of the stream processing. Unless you mean if we have abstracted the processing into its own method (and returning a `String` for example)...

Answer (score 1):

Regarding naming:

My first thought about a class named `CleanWords` without looking at its JavaDoc or implementation would be: "This class could implement [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) or extend one of the collection classes to contain clean words.".

My second thought after seeing the beginning of the class declaration without any of these: "This looks more like a name of a method that cleans words.".

I'd name the class `WordCleaner` and the method `cleanUp().` Such also better reflecting the challenge description.